# LINQ to XML query not working

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

Have a look on following XML:

```
<Countries>
   <country name="India">
      <State name="Maharashtra" capital="Mumbai" PIN="400001"/>
      <State Name="Uttar-Pradesh" capital="Lucknow" PIN="220001"/>
   </country>
   <country name="Sri-Lanka">
      <State name="Colombo" capital="Colombo" PIN="123456"/>
      <State name="Candy" capital="Jafana" PIN="654321"/>
   </country>
 </Countries>
```

when I use

```
public IEnumerable<CountryData> GetData()
{
     var results = from States in StockDoc.Descendants("Countries").Descendants("Country")
                      where (string)states.Attribute("Name") == "India"

                      select new CountryData
     {
        _State = (string)States.Element("Country").Element("State").Attribute("Name").Value,
        _Capital = (string)States.Element("Country").Element("State").Attribute("Capital").Value,
        _Pin= (string)States.Element("Country").Element("State").Attribute("PIN").Value
     };

      return results.ToList();
  }
```

This generates error on implementing. What is the probleme? Also, please define what above statement means?

I want to display all the countries in a dropdownbox like-

```
**India**
     Maharashtra
     Uttar-Pradesh
**Sri-Lanka**
     Colombo
     Candy
```

Also its corresponding values as capital and PIN should display in a label. How can I achieve this?

regards and thanks in advance

Comment: Please, provide error details

Comment: Does " error on implementing." mean compile error or runtime error? What does the error message say?

Answer (score 1):

Your query is wrong and **your xml has a mix of upper case and lower case attributes**. When I have trouble with LINQ to XML I split the query up into steps so I can more easily build the query I want.

The following is what you want:

```
// I've changed your xml to be consistent. Lowercase name and captial attributes
string xml = @"<Countries>
                   <country name=""India"">
                       <State name=""Maharashtra"" capital=""Mumbai"" PIN=""400001""/>
                       <State name=""Uttar-Pradesh"" capital=""Lucknow"" PIN=""220001""/>
                   </country>
                   <country name=""Sri-Lanka"">
                       <State name=""Colombo"" capital=""Colombo"" PIN=""123456""/>
                       <State name=""Candy"" capital=""Jafana"" PIN=""654321""/>
                   </country>
               </Countries>";

// Load the xml
XDocument StockDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

// Get states where country is "India"
IEnumerable<XElement> states = StockDoc.Root.Descendants("country")
                                       .Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("name") == "India")
                                       .Descendants("State");

// Build a new strongly typed IEnumerable<CountryData> from the xml states.
// Properties on classes in C# typically do not start with underscores. 
IEnumerable<CountryData> countryData = states.Select(y => new CountryData
                                                              {
                                                                  _State = (string)y.Attribute("name").Value,
                                                                  _Capital = (string)y.Attribute("capital").Value,
                                                                  _Pin = (string)y.Attribute("PIN").Value
                                                              });
```

What was wrong with your inital query:

```
var results = from States in StockDoc.Descendants("Countries").Descendants("Country")
                  where (string)states.Attribute("Name") == "India"
                  select new CountryData
 {
    _State = (string)States.Element("Country").Element("State").Attribute("Name").Value,
    _Capital = (string)States.Element("Country").Element("State").Attribute("Capital").Value,
    _Pin= (string)States.Element("Country").Element("State").Attribute("PIN").Value
 };
```

Your edited query in query syntax:

```
var results = from states in StockDoc.Descendants("Countries").Elements("country")
              where (string)states.Attribute("name") == "India"
              select states.Descendants("State")
              .Select(y => new CountryData
                           {
                               _State = (string)y.Attribute("name").Value,
                               _Capital = (string)y.Attribute("capital").Value,
                               _Pin = (string)y.Attribute("PIN").Value
                           });
```

Comment: This code is yet giving a run time error- "Null Reference...."  "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.". regards

Comment: I ran it, it doesn't. Copy and paste the first code section in my answer.

Comment: Thanks!!! It is working well. There was my fault.